# Replicating different set of tables to subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have transaction pull replication to several subscribers. Publisher has 2008 and distributer and subscribers have 2014.

I need one of the subscribers to replicate more tables. 
Is it possible to have different set of tables in subscribers?

Couldn't find such a scenario.

Thanks in advance

Liya

Comment: Its been a long time since I did replication, but wouldn't separating the tables into appropriate publications handle this?  Can't remember if Push vs. Pull has any bearing on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need to have a different publication created for a specific Subscriber with the required articles. This will help you in customizing your subscriber as per the required articles.